# Promise to array with PouchDB and AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash, pouchdb

I'm reading the allDocs() from a PouchDB database into an AngularJS variable:

```
var db = pouchService.db;
$scope.recordlist = db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true});
console.log($scope.recordlist);
```

I've noticed that it returns a promise, and when I try to read the array (and properties of the objects inside the array) using ng-repeat, it can't actually access the results, I guess because they are deeply nested.

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in recordlist | filter: shouldShow" 
     ng-class="{ 'msf-cancelled': record.cancelled, 'msf-commented' : record.comment}">
       <div class="col-md-1">{{record.time}}</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to turn this promise into a simple array of objects?

[image]

I have LoDash loaded in the app also, I don't know if it could be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the array after the promise was fulfilled (or show an error if an error happened):

```
$q.when(db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true}))
  .then(function (recordlist) {
    $scope.recordList = recordList;
    console.log($scope.recordlist);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

**Update:**
As Matt pointed out in the comments, if you're not using angular-pouch [angular-pouchdb](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb) wrapper then you will need to wrap the action in a `$scope.$apply()` to trigger the digest cycle or first convert the promise to an angular promise with `$q.when()`. I think converting the promise to an angular promise would also take care of logging errors, but you should always handle errors (show the user a message). You could do this of course with a global error handler.

Comment: This is not how I would do this in angular, as pouchDB does not translate directly into angular promises.

Comment: It gives Promises/A+ compatible promises, which is way more than you need for this simple case. I would only convert it if I wanted to pass it to some Angular function like resolve property for controllers, for instance. But in this case, not needed.

Comment: No, again this is completely wrong, and has nothing to do with the capabilities of the promises. Angular's promises are baked right into the digest cycle, where as pouchDB's are not. This means that in order for your line `$scope.recordList = recordList;` to work you need to include a `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: @MattWay, I'm using the [angular-pouch wrapper](https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb) to deal with this issue, this is probably why the answer from freshfilicio worked. Therefore I think  you are both right..

Comment: @MattWay I didn't downvote anything. You're right, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is accessing the promise, and the not the promise results. While `allDocs` does indeed return a promise, it is not an angular promise, so you should also wrap the promise in a `when` to get an actual angular promise.

```
var pouchPromise = db.allDocs({startkey: 'move_', endkey: 'move_\uffff', include_docs: true});
$q.when(pouchPromise).then(function(recordList){
    $scope.recordList = recordList;
    console.log($scope.recordlist);
});
```

I would read up on how promises work [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

It should be noted that this method of utilising pouch is outlined in the actual pouchDB docs here: http://pouchdb.com/api.html

Specifically:

> Using Ionic/Angular? You can wrap PouchDB promises in $q.when(). This will notify Angular to update the UI when the PouchDB promise has resolved.

This will allow you to avoid using `$scope.$apply()` when dealing with the asynchronous nature of non angular promises.